# Аdding elements to a DOM via a javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, append

Can you tell me how using only Javascript we can add elements to a html document? There is a **function** **createCards**() that creates cards, after that the **forEach** **method** fills these cards with content from some array. The last step remains, add to the document. I know that the prepend method is applicable here (and I don't like innerhtml... But I don't quite understand how to designate the element that I need to insert. Thanks a lot!

```js
const initialCards = [
  {
    name: 'place1',
    link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'place2',
    link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/chelyabinsk-oblast.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'place3',
    link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/ivanovo.jpg'
  },
];
const editProfile = document.querySelector('.profile__edit-button');
const popupProfile = document.querySelector('.popup__profile');
const popupNewPlace = document.querySelector('.popup-new-place');
const newPlaceButton = document.querySelector('.profile__add-button');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__close');
const yourName = document.querySelector('.profile__info-name');
const nameInput = popupProfile.querySelector('#profile-name');
const yourJob = document.querySelector('.profile__info-subtitle');
const jobInput = popupProfile.querySelector('#profile-job');
const formProfile = popupProfile.querySelector('.popup__edit-profile');
const formNewPlace = popupNewPlace.querySelector('.popup__edit-profile');
const contentItems = document.querySelector('.content');

function createCard (item) {
  const contentItemTemplate = document.getElementById('content-item').content;
  const newContentItem = contentItemTemplate.querySelector('.content__item').cloneNode(true);
  newContentItem.querySelector('.content__title').textContent = item.name;
  newContentItem.querySelector('.content__item-image').alt = item.name;
  newContentItem.querySelector('.content__item-image').src = item.link;
  newContentItem.querySelector('.content__like').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.target.classList.toggle('content__like_active');
  })
newContentItem.querySelector('.content__trash').addEventListener('click',function(event){
  (event.target.closest('.content__item')).remove();
});
  return newContentItem;
};
initialCards.forEach(createCard);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use appendChild() method, "document.querySelector('.containerForExample').appendChild('newContentItem)

Answer (score 0):

you should read these articles to get more familiar with how to create an element and add it to the DOM using javascript

[create Element function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

[append child function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[insert before function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

I hope that solves your problem. Thanks